# stanfordNER training does not recognize GPU present in the environment

Tags: java, python, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I have GPU(Tesla K80) present in the environment with CUDA installed. I am training stanfordNER on large data set with this Java command `java -Xms8g -cp stanford-corenlp-3.9.1.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop self.trainPropFileName`.  (FYI, This command is being executed inside a python file with 'os'package (i.e) `os.system(cmd)`).

During the training process CPU is being invoked instead of GPU. Can some one please suggest me an approach, so that GPU gets invoked. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you think CUDA is supported? afaik, this holds only when training the neural models of Stanford NLP. And [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html#a) is no GPU support mentioned

Answer (score 0):

The Java Stanford CoreNLP NER system does not have GPU support.